# How to remove '।' from a string in JavaScript or PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have some string like `"।।ॐम्।।"` and I want to remove `"।"` from the String using either JavaScript or PHP.
The string in UTF8 format.

I had tried something like

```
$str="।।ॐम्।।";

alert($str.replace(/।/g,''));
```

but । is not removing,output is same as input.In PHP I tried with `str_replace()` but no use.

Is there any way to do this?

---

```
       <?php

              header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

              $str=$_POST['arg'];

              $r=explode(" ",$str);

              echo "Before Replace -->  ".$r[6]."<br/>";

              $str1="।।ॐम्।।"; 

              $str1 = str_replace('।','',$str1);  

              $str2 = str_replace('।','',$r[6]); 

              echo "After Replace --><br/><br/> str1: ".$str1."         <br/>str2: ".$str2;  

              ?>
```

Not working. See the Output.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmwWx.png)

### Output:

Before Replace --> ।।ॐम्।।अथषड्विंशतिसूत्रप्रारंभः।।हरिःॐम्।।इ

After Replace -->

str1: ॐम्

str2: ।।ॐम्।।अथषड्विंशतिसूत्रप्रारंभः।।हरिःॐम्।।इ

Comment: In JavaScript `string.replace(/।/g, '')`

Comment: you forgot a parenthesis: $str="।।ॐम्।।";alert($str.replace(/।/g,''));

Comment: Add a parenthesis at the end, it works.

Comment: In PHP you could use: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Tried with evey option . When string is given manualy it is working file but when it is taken through argument(which is read from file) it is not working.

Comment: @AVINASH Make sure that everything uses UTF8. Most likely the file in which it's saved in is not UTF8 but the input is (or the other way around). The files have to be UTF8. The connection has to be UTF8 and lastly your database has to be UTF8.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a simple `trim()`, if you're only expecting same character on both ends.

```
<?php

$string = '।।ॐम्।।';
echo trim($string,'।'); //ॐम्
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for javascript

```
var str="।।ॐम्।।"; 
alert(str.replace(/।/g,''));
```

Use this code for PHP

```
<?php
$str="।।ॐम्।।"; 
$str = trim(str_replace("।","",$str));
echo $str;
?>
```

This works...

Answer (score 0):

`"।।ॐम्।।".replace(/[।]/g, "");` output `ॐम्`

> Be careful ! '।' isn't a pipe '|'

Answer (score 0):

This code may Help you:

```
$string = '।।ॐम्।।';
$newData = str_replace('&#124;','',$string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone . I got answer.

This worked for me.

```
     $str2 = str_replace('&#2404;','',$r[6]);
```